# Logic App and ServiceBus sessions: is it required to close the session?

Tags: session, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App in charge of receiving messages from a ServiceBus queue/subscription where session is enabled.
Each time my Logic App reads messages from the ServiceBus queue, it dequeues messages within the same session and in the future (1 or more days after), other messages can be published with the same session (my Logic App will not be alive anymore and a new one will be instanciated).
My question is: may I close the session at a particular time? For example after having read all messages that were in the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can close the session using the session Id once you are done with reading all messages. But, I am curious why you are instantiating a new logic app after some time to process the new messages on the same session. What is your scenario around it? You can also share more details with me @ rarayudu@microsoft.com